# application of linear algebra to nonlinear dynamic systems

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

I've thought of something and I have some questions about it.  Consider the following transformation:

$$Q(x,y,z)=(x^2 + 2yz, y^2 + 2xz, z^2 + 2xy)$$.

If for every nonnegative integer t,

$$(x_{t+1},y_{t+1},z_{t+1}) = Q(x_t,y_t,z_t),$$

$$X_t = $$
            \begin{pmatrix}
         x_t & z_t & y_t \\
         y_t & x_t & z_t \\ 
         z_t & y_t & x_t \\
         \end{pmatrix}

and $$C = $$
               \begin{pmatrix}
           1 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 1 \\
           0 & 1 & 0  \\
           \end{pmatrix}

then $$X_{t+1} = C \cdot X_t^2 \cdot C^{-1}$$

so $$X_t = C^t \cdot X_0^{2^t} \cdot C^{-t}.$$

It is always possible to find a closed-form solution for all of the components 
of the powers of a square matrix by reducing the matrix to Jordan canonical form.  In this case as in almost all cases, it is possible to diagonalize the matrices C and $X_0.$  In this way, one can get a closed-form solution for $x_t,$ $y_t$ and $z_t.$  More generally, $X_0$ can be any nxn circulant matrix 
and C can be any nxn permutation matrix, allowing one to solve a discrete 
dynamical system in n variables.  Even more generally, $X_0$ can be any nxn 
matrix and C can be any invertible nxn matrix, allowing one to solve a discrete dynamical system in n or $n^2$ variables.

Next consider the following system of differential equations,

dx/dt = $x^2$ + yz   $\quad$       dy/dt = xy + yw

dz/dt = xz + zw       $\quad$      dw/dt = $w^2$ +yz.

Let X(t) = $$
          \begin{pmatrix}
           x(t) & y(t)\\
           z(t) & w(t)\\
           \end{pmatrix}
        $$

Then dX(t)/dt = $[X(t)]^2$ so $X(t) = X(0)  [I - t  X(0)]^{-1}.$

I have checked this and it works.  Some other solvable matrix differential 
equations are

dX(t)/dt = $[X(t)]^2$ + X(t);

dX(t)/dt = $[X(t)]^2$ - X(t);

and

dX(t)/dt = $[X(t)]^2$ - I.

Again X(0) can be any nxn matrix, allowing one to solve a system of $n^2$ 
differential equations in $n^2$ variables.

So I have two questions about this.  First, is all of this already known?
And second, if it is, where can I read about it?

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345169/using-linear-algebra-to-find-closed-form-solutions-of-some-nonlinear-dynamical-s